# Javascript: Using object's field's value to determine another object literal's field's name

Tags: javascript

I want to use object's field's value while creating another object using literal notation:

```
var T = {
 fieldName : 'testField'
};
/*
// Doesn't work.
var test = {
 T.fieldName : 'value'
};
*/
// Does work.
var test = [];
test[T.fieldName] = 'value';
alert(test.testField);          // test
```

But it doesn't work.
Is there a way to solve this issue or using square brackets is the only way out?

**Upd.:** Removed non-working code.

Comment: You haven't tried to run the code you posted, have you?

Comment: Oops, it somehow seemed to work for me. Removed wrong code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var T = {
 fieldName : 'testField'
};
var dummy = T.fieldName;        // dummy variable
var test = {
 dummy : 'value'
};
alert(test.testField);          // test
```

That should not work. The value 'value' will be stored in test.dummy, not test.testField. The way to do it would be:

```
var T = {
 fieldName : 'testField'
};
// Does work.
var test = {};
test[T.fieldName] = 'value';
alert(test.testField);          // alerts "value"
```

Which is what you already have

Comment: It somehow seemed to work for me :). Tested and removed it from the question as wrong code.

Answer (score 2):

Your "test" variable is Array, not Object.

You should create "test" like "= {}" instead of "= []".

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is.

```
var T={
    testField : 'testField'
};

     eval ('var test = {' + T.testField + ':' +  value + '}');
```

And you make this generic, something like this

```
function MakeVar(varName,fieldToUse,valueToPass)
{
      var res = 'var ' +varName+ '= {' + T.testField + ':' +  value + '}'
     eval(res);
}

var T={
    testField : 'testField'
};


     MakeVar('test',T.testField,'value');
     var outt=test.testField;
```

Hope this helps